# OpenFileDialog freezes application/GUI when I click button

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog

I have seen multiple questions about this problem and attempted several solutions but none seem to work, maybe I've missed out something.

```
private void ButtonBrowseProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
     {
          openFileDialog.Title = "Upload Profile Image";
          openFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp;*.png";
          if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
               pictureBoxProfile.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
     }
}
```

The dialog box does not show up, the debug app just freezes and becomes unclickable

WinForm, .NET Framework 4.8 | 528040

Comment: is this WinForm? or wpf?

Comment: It's in WinForm

Comment: how about remove using? is that same as before?

Comment: I have tried that before but not working. Using is usually just to auto close the dialog, and not write ```openFileDialog.Close();```

Comment: is that also doesn't work on new application which is newly created? if then, I gurss it's PC problem. if not, some part of code causes error which is not in the post...

Comment: i tried code is working fine

Comment: You might want to give ShowDialog a reference to the parent form. Otherwise the dialog might be shown beneath the other windows.